# How to have a Sublime Text plugin override the user's default "auto_complete_selector" setting?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublimetext, code-snippets, sublime-text-plugin

The rationale for this is to build an ESLint rule auto-completion plugin, but of course, I don't want ESLint rule autocompletes suggested outside my comments, and I also don't want to have to enable all suggestions within comments.

I'm trying to replicate the behavior [like in this VSCode plugin for the same purpose.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=drKnoxy.eslint-disable-snippets)

I'm also not entirely certain if this behavior requires autocomplete, snippets, or both?

For those unaware of ESLint's comment syntax, it's like this:

```
var a = 1; // eslint-disable-line RULE_NAME
```

Comment: You want to disable autocompletes between two commands in comments or only in line with command in comment?

Comment: @ToTamire I'm not sure I understand your question, can you clarify it? I want to _enable_ autocomplete in comments, but only after the specific syntax `eslint-disable-line` followed by whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the conditions your are setting i.e.

1. The completions should appear only in comments.
2. The completions should appear only after certain word(s) (in this case `eslint-disable` and family).

you'll need to write a custom plugin that supplies the completions and also keeps track of where the completions are to be presented.

The following is a plugin that accomplishes this (It mimics the VS Code counterpart)

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class ESLintListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):

    eslint_completions = ["camelcase","default-case","func-names","global-require","import/prefer-default-export","indent","max-len","new-cap","no-alert","no-cond-assign","no-confusing","no-console","no-extend-native","no-mixed-operators","no-new","no-param-reassign","no-shadow","no-undef","no-unused-vars","prefer-arrow-callback","prefer-rest-params","react/prop-types","wrap-iife"]

    def on_query_completions(self, view, prefix, locations):
        if not view.match_selector(locations[0] - 1, "source.js comment"):
            return

        if (
            view.substr(sublime.Region(locations[0] - 16, locations[0] - 2)) == "eslint-disable" or
            view.substr(sublime.Region(locations[0] - 21, locations[0] - 2)) == "eslint-disable-line" or
            view.substr(sublime.Region(locations[0] - 26, locations[0] - 2)) == "eslint-disable-next-line"
        ):
            return [
                sublime.CompletionItem(
                    trigger=item,
                    annotation=item,
                    details="Eslint rule",
                    kind=(sublime.KIND_ID_FUNCTION, "E", "Eslint")
                )
                for item in self.eslint_completions
            ]

        return None
```

The first `if` condition check for condition (1) and the second one check for condition (2) and also returns the desired completions if it matches.

[image]

Note that this doesn't auto complete the `eslint` related words, but only the rule name after that.

I have used some new ST4 features just for a little spice (& also to provide a bit more details of what the completions are).

In order for this to work, you need to have `source.js comment` in your `auto_complete_selector` since completions are by default disable in comments.

**Edit** (based on comments):

To avoid word & explicit completions, we use the two flags as shown below. This should mitigate other completions being shown in the AC to some extent.

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class ESLintListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):

    eslint_completions = ["camelcase","default-case","func-names","global-require","import/prefer-default-export","indent","max-len","new-cap","no-alert","no-cond-assign","no-confusing","no-console","no-extend-native","no-mixed-operators","no-new","no-param-reassign","no-shadow","no-undef","no-unused-vars","prefer-arrow-callback","prefer-rest-params","react/prop-types","wrap-iife"]

    def on_query_completions(self, view, prefix, locations):
        if not view.match_selector(locations[0] - 1, "source.js comment"):
            return

        if (
            view.substr(sublime.Region(locations[0] - 16, locations[0] - 2)) == "eslint-disable" or
            view.substr(sublime.Region(locations[0] - 21, locations[0] - 2)) == "eslint-disable-line" or
            view.substr(sublime.Region(locations[0] - 26, locations[0] - 2)) == "eslint-disable-next-line"
        ):
            return (
                [
                    sublime.CompletionItem(
                        trigger=item,
                        annotation=item,
                        details="Eslint rule",
                        kind=(sublime.KIND_ID_FUNCTION, "E", "Eslint")
                    )
                    for item in self.eslint_completions
                ],
                sublime.INHIBIT_WORD_COMPLETIONS | sublime.INHIBIT_EXPLICIT_COMPLETIONS
            )

        return None
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! So there's no way to limit the autocompletions though? It's only possible to add these if we enable ALL autocompletions in comments? Because unfortunately what happens is that the autosuggestions end up being totally unrelated to ESLint because it offers every possible suggestion, ESLint related or not, and the ESLint ones often fall too far down the list to make the suggest feature any use in that case. [Example of the problem](https://imgur.com/a/h90iBfJ)

Comment: Also, I guess autocomplete strings can't contain slashes, because `react/prop-types` can't be suggested or autocompleted it seems like.

Comment: `react/prop-types` seems to be auto completed just fine for me on Build 4106 (Windows). As for your other question, the auto completions needs to be turned on in comments, so that the completions from this plugin are shown. You can mitigate the issue with other completions to some extent though (see the Edit of the answer). Apart from that, there isn't much to be done in this regard.

Comment: Hmm.. Build 4107 on Windows is where I'm seeing the issue with `react/prop-types`. Strange. But in any event, that's beyond the scope of my original question. Thanks very much for your edit to try to further mitigate the problematic suggestions. While this isn't a true solution to the question, I do believe you've given the best answer within the confines of Sublime's existing capabilities. Thank you again!